# Sync Apple notes app on MacBook to Android

Tags: macos, notes.app, android, google-sync

I recently got an Android phone, and I wanted to know how to sync Apple Notes to Google Keep. I have added my Gmail account to the Apple Notes app, but I don't see the notes showing up in Google Keep. What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synchronizing Apple Notes to Gmail puts the notes under a Notes section within Gmail itself.

Google Keep has a synchronization feature, but it's only accessible from Google Keep apps on other platforms and cannot sync with or import from any non-Keep apps. Several years ago, [Google stated](http://www.computerworld.com/article/3026239/android/google-keep-3-years.html) they were going to be introducing sync to Google Drive within a few weeks, but that never materialized. (The only available interaction with Google Drive is to export a note to Drive as a document, but the reverse is not possible.)

Your options are to continue to use Apple Notes and interact with them in Gmail, or to use the [Google Keep web app](https://keep.google.com) or a relatively poorly-reviewed [Chrome app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-keep-notes-and-lis/hmjkmjkepdijhoojdojkdfohbdgmmhki).